# WolframAlpha API: how to specify multiple pods?

Tags: perl, rest, wolframalpha

Currently I am specifying multiple pods in the following way:

```
my $q = $wa->query(
        'input' => $input,
        'format' => 'plaintext',
        'includepodid' => ['Input', 'Result', 'WeatherForecast:WeatherData', 'ForecastCharts:WeatherData'],
        'reinterpret' => 'true',
);
```

However it then returns empty result – number of pods is undefined, so as are other fields. Setting only a single pod id with:

```
'includepodid' => 'Result'
```

does work so the code is overall correct. Using `[ 'Result' ]` yields the same incorrect behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's maybe a little late for you but for anyone else experiencing this: You mustn't set the `includepodid` parameter with delimiters you have to set it multiple times meaning instead of this:

```
...&includepodid=ID1,ID2
```

do this:

```
...&includepodid=ID1&includepodid=ID2
```

Worked for me though..